# how to get the end of html page in android webview

Tags: android, html, webview

i'm displaying a web page in android webview. and i want to trigger a message when the user reaches end of page while scrolling. how can i do that? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is we can write custom MyWebView class that extends WebView and then we can use the function called computeHorizontalScrollRange() orcomputeVirticalScrollRange() to get the scroll range of webview.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't think there is any event that triggers this. But here's one way - you will have to try and see if it works though. Have a `ListView` with two rows - one having the `WebViewClient` and another just an ordinary `TextView` - You could use something like [`SackOfViewsAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist) for this.

In your adapter's `getView()`, when the function is called to display the bottom `TextView`, that's your cue on the user having scrolled down.